# Simple MVC Framework for ASP.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, frameworks

I need a simple MVC framework, without jQuery extensions, hibernate, loggers, etc..

Only Model-View-Controller functions. Anyone have an idea where I can find one?

Comment: Um... ASP.NET MVC? (http://www.asp.net/mvc/)

Comment: You could employ your own MVC pattern with normal WebForms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I second on the [Vici MVC framework](http://viciproject.com/mvc)! Open source, easy to setup, easy to learn, lightweight, powerfull and with a good support channel through a StackExchange-based webpage.

The [Vici Project](http://viciproject.com) comes with a lot more libraries (e.g. [Vici CoolStorage](http://viciproject.com/coolstorage) = ORM) which work beautifully together.

Answer (score 18):

Does the [official ASP.Net MVC framework](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28d35rmemuuono1wvm1gsp2n45%29%29/mvc/) not meet your needs?  It doesn't come with loggers, ORM's or anything like that.  And it is extremely flexible and extensible.

Yes, by default it includes jQuery libraries in any new projects you start... but those are simple to remove, and are not part of the framework itself.  There is no reliance on them.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need jquery, then simply delete it from your ASP.NET MVC project.

Two alternative MVC frameworks would be: [Vici.MVC](http://viciproject.com/wiki/projects/mvc/home), [FubuMVC](http://code.google.com/p/fubumvc/)

Answer (score 6):

Other MVC frameworks that haven't been mentioned here:

- [MonoRail](http://castleproject.org/monorail/index.html) (2.0 was released today)
- [Bistro](http://bistroframework.org) (great F# support)

Answer (score 3):

http://asp.net/mvc is the only ASP.NET framework I know off. It's very basic out of the box, and it's up to you what you add to it.

It allows you to add to it whatever you need and doesn't force you to use anything except the MVC design pattern and ASP.NET.

It's very simple in that all you really need to worry about is Models, Views and Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Go with ASP.NET MVC.  That's about as simple as it comes.  If that's too complex, I'd suggest regular webforms or MVC on a different platform (like CakePHP)

Answer (score 0):

I've designed a minimalistic MVC framework for ASP.Net named [BarelyMVC](https://bitbucket.org/earlz/barelymvc/). It's BSD licensed and currently at an alpha release.

It gets it's name because it's quite literally barely an MVC framework. It attempts to take all of the magic out of the equation and lets you directly control many aspects of how things work. There are no magical attributes. It consists of a simple stateless authentication system, a statically compiled view system made using T4, and a powerful Router and set of classes for handling HTTP requests. When put together it can make for very clear and easy to read/write code that you know exactly what it does. It also takes a hands off approach to architecture. When something you write doesn't mesh well with the traditional MVC architecture, it's trivial to work around that.